# VNC with virtual display - black screen when I connect

Tags: display, vnc, xrandr, dock

I have a Ubuntu machine that I use as a Plex and data server. There is no monitor connected to it. This wasn't a problem with Ubuntu 16.04, but now, with 18.04, it is and it shows a black screen whenever I connect using VNC.

I've already created the virtual display using the answer to this question: [Add virtual output to Xorg](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/378373/add-virtual-output-to-xorg)

> Create a `20-intel.conf` file:
>
> ```
> sudo vi /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf
> ```
>
> Add the following configuration information into the file:
>
> ```
> Section "Device"
>     Identifier "intelgpu0"
>     Driver "intel"
>     Option "VirtualHeads" "2"
> EndSection
> ```
>
> This tells the Intel GPU to create 2 virtual displays. You can change
> the number of VirtualHeads to your needs.

Then I made a shell script (don't forget to set executable) and put that in Startup Applications:

```
#! /bin/bash
/usr/bin/xrandr -d :0 --output VIRTUAL1 --primary --auto
/usr/bin/xrandr --newmode "1600x900_60.00" 118.25 1600 1696 1856 2112 900$
/usr/bin/xrandr --addmode VIRTUAL1 "1600x900_60.00"
```

After this, it still shows a black screen when I connect using VNC. BUT, when I run this with SSH:

```
export DISPLAY=:0
xrandr
```

After that, I can see my desktop in VNC... Any ideas on how to fix this? Also, when I see my desktop after all this, the dock is missing and all the icons are in the same spot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added `/usr/bin/xrandr` to the end of the script:

```
#! /bin/bash

/usr/bin/xrandr -d :0 --output VIRTUAL1 --primary --auto
/usr/bin/xrandr --newmode "1600x900_60.00" 118.25 1600 1696 1856 2112 900$
/usr/bin/xrandr --addmode VIRTUAL1 "1600x900_60.00"
/usr/bin/xrandr
```

That way, `VIRTUAL1` is set as output and connected. At boot, a new mode (found using `cvt 1600 900`) is being created and appointed to `VIRTUAL1`.

Only issue with this is: dock is missing at reboot... Haven't solved that yet.

Comment: Add `killall -3 gnome-shell` at the end to restart GNOME - it brings back the panel. The line `--output VIRTUAL1 --primary --auto` seems to be not necessary for me, the `--newmode "1600x900_60.00" 118.25 1600 1696 1856 2112 900$` gives errors, so I had to regenerate with cvt. Other thing is that the new screens are placed one alongside another by default.