# How to force a virtual monitor to be always secondary?

Tags: command-line, multiple-monitors, display, vnc, xrandr

Created a virtual display so VNC can work when there is no physical display:

`/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf`:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier "intelgpu0"
    Driver "intel"
    Option "VirtualHeads" "2"
EndSection
```

Startup script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

/usr/bin/xrandr -d :0 --newmode "1600x900_60.00"  118.25  1600 1696 1856 2112  900 903 908 934 -hsync +vsync
/usr/bin/xrandr -d :0 --addmode VIRTUAL1 "1600x900_60.00"
/usr/bin/xrandr -d :0
killall -3 gnome-shell
```

As in https://askubuntu.com/a/1062890/391744

But when plugging in the real monitors they are appearing as secondaries. They show the uninteresting part with no graphical programs visible and no panels/docks.

How to configure it that any non-virtual monitor would automatically become a primary?

For the moment I've only come up with this addition to the script to poll the connected monitors with `xrandr`:

```bsh
(
    while [ 1 ]; do
        xrandr_out="$(LANG=C /usr/bin/xrandr -d :0)"
        # If VIRTUAL is primary.
        if egrep -q '^VIRTUAL[0-9]+[[:space:]]+connected[[:space:]]+primary' < <(printf '%s\n' "$xrandr_out"); then
            # Find non-virtual that is connected.
            non_virt="$(sed -nre 's/^([^[:space:]]+)[[:space:]]+connected.*/\1/p' < <(printf '%s\n' "$xrandr_out" | grep -v ^VIRTUAL) | head -n1)"
            if [ -n "$non_virt" ]; then
                xrandr -d :0 --output "$non_virt" --primary --pos 0x0
            fi
        fi
        sleep 10
    done
) & disown
```